# QTCreator debug with external dll

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, sqlite, dllimport

**Hi everyone!**

The following will be a problem that i *solved* but it maybe *usefull* for somebody.

I have a project that I started with *Visual Studio 2015* , because i wanted to have *GUI* I am changing from Visual Studio to QTCreator.(Yea i know, why not started it already in QT)

So I have worked couple of times already with QTCreator nothing serious. I used it's debugger without any problem.

### Moving from VS->QT , plain C++ application

I moved all file into a separate folder. I started a Plain C++ Application.(I had to include later the QT framework when I couldn't include ,I added these lines into .pro file :**QT += core gui QT += widgets** )

The debugger is not working.

1. I build in debug
2. I press F5, or click on the debug build option
3. I placed a breakpoint

The debugger just skips the placed breakpoint.I don't know why but when I edit the breakpoint's type to be:Break on memory address
then the debugger works,and halts at the placed breakpoint,and i see the assembly code.

### Then I started a new QT Widgets Application

and hoped it will work,but it did not.

I have read guides on forums, also here. None of them solved the problem.

My attempts:

1. dependency walker
2. edited the .pro file ,so the includes are fine
3. changed the tool kits, and debugger(debugger and tool kits are 32bit)
4. **checked the sqlite3 dll to be 32bit version,also tried 64bit**

### I narrowed down the list of possible problems

I want to use **sqlite3** and build a GUI with QT, I started thinking maybe the problem is in the including process .

My .pro file looks like

```css
...

HEADERS += \

... 

resources/sqlite3QT/sqlite3.h \

INCLUDEPATH += resources/

DISTFILES += \
    resources/sqlite3QT/sqlite3.lib

#
LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/resources/sqlite3QT" -lsqlite3

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/resources/sqlite3QT/ -lsqlite3
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/resources/sqlite3QT/ -lsqlite3
```

The commented line 
#
LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/resources/sqlite3QT" -lsqlite3
 was also another try to include the .lib in a different manner.

So if I *comment out all the sqlite3 objects and my functions that use any of sqlite3 the debugger works and stops* at the placed breakpoint.

Okay so all the headers ,sources and one library are included correctly. 
What else needs to be included?

.dll file maybe, so because i use windows and i know that the OS will search for the .dll ,and where the .exe is located there the OS starts looking first,I placed .dll into the /debug/ folder.Because when i compile with QT in debug mode this is where everything is placed.

### No more CDB error

It's solved the problem so I no longer get the "Unexpected CDB Exit" labeled ,"The CDB process terminated." error.

Little "experiment" i tried to place the 64bit version instead the 32bit version of sqlite3.dll , in my case the same error happened(with 32bit cdb.exe and 32bit toolchain)